# Creating custom OL8 ISO fails to find grub2 package

Tags: iso-image, grub2, anaconda, oracle-linux, kickstart

I'm trying to build a custom Oracle Linux 8 ISO using the steps described here:

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/create-custom-iso-rhel-centos-8/

Everything starts out fine, the ISO is bootable, the kickstart file loads and disks are partitioned. When it gets to the software installation stage it fails with this error:

```
Problems in request:
missing packages: grub2
```

The `grub2*` RPMs are included in the ISO:

```
EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg
EFI/BOOT/grubia32.efi
EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi
isolinux/grub.conf
BaseOS/Packages/grub2-efi-x64-2.02-99.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
BaseOS/Packages/grub2-common-2.02-99.0.2.el8.noarch.rpm
BaseOS/Packages/grub2-tools-extra-2.02-99.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
BaseOS/Packages/grub2-tools-2.02-99.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
BaseOS/Packages/grub2-tools-minimal-2.02-99.0.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
BaseOS/Packages/grubby-8.40-41.0.1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

grub2 means

> grub2-pc: grub2-pc-2.02-99.el8.x86_64.rpm
> grub2-pc-modules: grub2-pc-modules-2.02-99.el8.noarch.rpm

Also in BaseOS/Packages dir too. Find them and cp them in your custom BaseOS/Package.
Rerun createrepo to update.